# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to study the character of this series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n}$$
and I tried with the root criterion:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt [n]\frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n} =
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2} n^{\frac{\sqrt n}{n}}=
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (n^{\frac{1}{n}})^ {\sqrt n}$

$n^{\frac{1}{n}}$
 tends to 1, then $(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^ {\sqrt n}$ tends to 1
and the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$
So the given series converges.

Is it right?

Comment: "$n^\frac{1}{n}$ tends to $1$, then $(n^\frac{1}{n})^\sqrt{n}$ tends to $1$" this is not immediate. You need to prove this.

Comment: Perhaps like this: $n^{1/√n}=(√n)^{1/√n}(√n)^{1/√n}$. The limit of each factor exists( =1), hence the limit of the product is?

Comment: $\dfrac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^n} =\left(\dfrac{n}{2^\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n} \leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^\sqrt{n} \to 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful saying "$n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ tends to $1$, then $(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\sqrt{n}}$ tends to $1$". While this may be true, your reasoning is flawed. In order to show it's true, note that

$$(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\sqrt{n}}=n^{n^{-1/2}}=\exp(\log(n^{n^{-1/2}}))=\exp(n^{-1/2}\log(n))$$

Using the continuity of the exponential, we know that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(n^{-1/2}\log(n))=\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-1/2}\log(n)))$$

But this limit is easy as the logarithm grows slower than any power of $n$. This implies

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(n^{-1/2}\log(n))=\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-1/2}\log(n)))=\exp(0)=1$$

This concludes the proof.